# How to fix jBoss Error "MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."*.war".component."

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I have Maven webApp project when I deploy this project on wildfly 15.0.1.Final using IntelliJ Idea following errors are appearing. Please help me, how to resolve these errors. I am using Spring MVC 5.1.4.RELEASE also. I also have tried to change the spring version but same error. Alos delete all deployments and tem folder in wildfly but no success.

**Error:**

```
12:23:18,228 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-1) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
12:23:18,650 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteProcessor in Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)


12:23:18,650 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber in Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)


12:23:18,665 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor in Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:836)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

12:23:18,665 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."F2ASTWeb.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."F2ASTWeb.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1730)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.InjectionTargets.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:836)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)

    ... 12 more

12:23:18,665 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."F2ASTWeb.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."F2ASTWeb.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1730)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    ... 12 more

12:23:18,665 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerReadPublisher in Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)


12:23:18,681 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher in Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher


12:23:18,697 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."F2ASTWeb.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."F2ASTWeb.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service

Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener

    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module "deployment.F2ASTWeb.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher

    ... 12 more

12:23:18,728 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "F2ASTWeb.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber"
}}
12:23:18,728 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "F2ASTWeb.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber"
}}
12:23:18,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = F2ASTWeb.war_org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver_1_0
12:23:18,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = F2ASTWeb.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
12:23:18,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = F2ASTWeb.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
12:23:18,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = F2ASTWeb.war_com.hxtt.sql.excel.ExcelDriver_6_0
12:23:19,322 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment F2ASTWeb.war (runtime-name: F2ASTWeb.war) in 590ms
[2019-05-02 12:23:19,400] Artifact F2AST-Web:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2019-05-02 12:23:19,400] Artifact F2AST-Web:war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor","jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher","jboss.deployment.unit.\"F2ASTWeb.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module \"deployment.F2ASTWeb.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber"}}
```

Comment: Java EE, Microprofile and Spring? Do you really need them all? Looks like it is not finding some Spring classes, where do you expect them to be?

Comment: You are missing the class `org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse` could be please add your pom.xml and the content of your war lib folder

Comment: @PanuHaaramo I have resolved this issue by adding the following dependency. But still, I am unable to understand the root cause of this issue. 
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Muhammad Athar Aziz* mentioned in the comments, this does the trick:

```
 <dependency> 
     <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId> 
     <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId> 
     <version>1.0.0</version> 
 </dependency>
```